# Не могу понять как связать сущности в EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net

подскажите как связать эти две сущности, что бы в бд создавались 2 связанные таблицы. Читаю статью на метаните и не могу понять.
Появляется ошибка **InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'Employee' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'DepartmentId'.**

```
public class Department 
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    

}
public class Employee
{
     [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Adress { get; set; } = null!;
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Department Department { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Description { get; set; }

}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; } = null!;

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasData(
            new Department { DepartmentId = 1, Name = "Dev" },
            new Department { DepartmentId = 2, Name = "Marketing" },
            new Department { DepartmentId = 3, Name = "Art" });
        
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(
            new Employee { Id = 1, FirstName = "Максим", LastName = "Максимов",Department = new(1,"DepName1"), DateOfBirth = "22.11.1990", Adress = "Novosibirsk", Description = "" },
            new Employee { Id = 2, FirstName = "Иван", LastName = "Иванов", Department = new(2, "DepName2"), DateOfBirth = "12.02.1996", Adress = "SPB", Description = ""},
            new Employee { Id = 3, FirstName = "Дмитрий", LastName = "Дмитриев", Department = new(3, "DepName3"), DateOfBirth = "10.06.1998",Adress = "MSK", Description = ""});
       
    }

   
}
```

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Department >().HasData()` для начала добавьте в таблицу `Department`, а потом в `Employee`. И во вторых, обратную связь с таблицы `Department` с таблицей `Employee` сделайте для удобства в будущем.

Comment: Немного изменил сущности и код, но все равно не могу понять как к модели "Employee" привязать "Department", подскажите по шагам пожалуйста, я только учусь и поэтому много туплю.

Comment: public virtual Department Department { get; set; }  Посмотрите гайд: https://codeteddy.com/2018/10/04/learning-entity-framework-day-2-code-first-approach-and-code-first-migrations-in-entity-framework/

Comment: The seed entity for entity type 'Employee' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Department' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'Employee' and specify the foreign key values {'DepartmentId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

Comment: в гайде всё показано в картинках, внимательно посмотрите. [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")] уберите

Comment: простым языком: Department содержит Employee, а не наоборот, как у вас

Comment: Собственно  вот само руководство как сделать https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/3.1.php

Comment: И в `modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData` не добавляйте новый объект `Department`, а используйте `Employee.DepartmentId`. Так как ранее уже в таблице `Department` есть записи, он сам подставит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте на простых примерах.
Классы сущностей:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Я удалил все остальные свойства, чтобы они не мешались.

Атрибут `[Key]` можно не указывать, если свойство соответствует соглашениям: имеет название `Id` или `<Entity>Id` (`EmployeeId`, `DepartmentId`). Но если хотите, можете его оставить.

Атрибут `[ForeignKey(...)]` тоже можно не указывать, если имя соответствует принятым соглашениям.

Для образования связи один-ко-многим (one-to-many) у нас должна быть коллекция (например, `List<Employee>`) с одной стороны и одиночное свойство соответствующего типа (`Department`) с другой стороны. Entity Framework сам создаст необходимые связи.

---

Теперь перейдём к заполнению данных.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasData(
        new Department { Id = 1, Name = "Dev" },
        new Department { Id = 2, Name = "Marketing" },
        new Department { Id = 3, Name = "Art" }
    );

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(
        new Employee { Id = 11, DepartmentId = 1, FirstName = "Максим" },
        new Employee { Id = 12, DepartmentId = 2, FirstName = "Иван" },
        new Employee { Id = 13, DepartmentId = 3, FirstName = "Дмитрий" }
    );
}
```

Этот код работает, при условии, что айдишники заданы вручную.
Обратите внимание, что номера 1, 2 и 3 совпадают.
Причём указать их нужно обязательно, т. к. свойства `DepartmentId` и `Department` сделаны non-nullable.

Если их сделать nullable:

```
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department? Department { get; set; }
```

то в методе `HasData` можно будет опустить задание `DepartmentId`. Данные будут вставлены, но связи между ними не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Связь образуется благодаря вызову "Has" на одной из сторон отношения.
В вашем случе нужно добавить дополнительное свойство к Департаменту

```
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

а затем объявить связь "1-ко-многим" между этими сущностями, добавив следующий вызов в конфигурацию Департамента:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Department)
        .WithMany(u => u.Employees)
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.DepartmentId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();
```